# Any information on support of SonarQube LTS?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

Currently there is a 4.5.x LTS version and a 5.4.x LATEST version. Is there any information until when the 5.x LTS will be supported? (Q3/16 or 2020 or forever)

Thanks

Christian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next Long-Term Support version will be 5.6. It is planned to be released in May/June.